# Problem initializing array of struct{enum;union;}

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, unions

I have a problem defining `s_arr[10]` which is supposed to be an array of struct objects, while the struct contains an enum and a union member:

```
enum E {ENUM_A,ENUM_B};
union U {
  String s;
  char c[4];
};
struct S {
  E e;
  U u;
};

S s_arr[10];
```

I have tried to solve this in different ways, but none of them worked.
Essentially I get the following compilation error:

```
sketch_mar16a:13:11: error: use of deleted function 'S::S()'
 S s_arr[10];
           ^
/.../sketch_mar16a.ino:8:8: note: 'S::S()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 struct S {
        ^
sketch_mar16a:8:8: error: use of deleted function 'U::U()'
/.../sketch_mar16a.ino:4:7: note: 'U::U()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 union U {
       ^
sketch_mar16a:5:10: error: union member 'U::s' with non-trivial 'String::String(const char*)'
   String s;
          ^
sketch_mar16a:8:8: error: use of deleted function 'U::~U()'
 struct S {
        ^
/.../sketch_mar16a/sketch_mar16a.ino:4:7: note: 'U::~U()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 union U {
       ^
sketch_mar16a:5:10: error: union member 'U::s' with non-trivial 'String::~String()'
   String s;
          ^
sketch_mar16a:13:11: error: use of deleted function 'S::~S()'
 S s_arr[10];
           ^
/.../sketch_mar16a/sketch_mar16a.ino:8:8: note: 'S::~S()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 struct S {
        ^
sketch_mar16a:8:8: error: use of deleted function 'U::~U()'
/.../sketch_mar16a.ino: In function 'void __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
sketch_mar16a:13:3: error: use of deleted function 'S::~S()'
 S s_arr[10];
   ^
exit status 1
use of deleted function 'S::S()'
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand where the error message is trying to point me to. I tried to define initializers for the involved classes, but I don't know how (or where) to define an initializer for the union.

Using google, I only found cases where a union contains a struct, but I could not derive the solution for my problem.

Can you explain me, why the "default definition would be ill-formed"? How would the default definition look like and when during compile time does it happen?
**NOTE:** the code is compiled for an arduino uno using the Arduino IDE

Comment: Maybe it's something specific to your compiler, but can you tell me what `String` is?

Comment: @AdrianMole `String` is an arduino class for strings. I tried with different datatypes, but it makes no difference...

Comment: There are many reasons why the default constructor can be deleted. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.ctor#5 for details.

Comment: @RSahu well, in my case, the constructor is deleted "because the default definition would be ill-formed" and I don't understand what this is telling me...

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the following error messages:

> ```
> sketch_mar16a:8:8: error: use of deleted function 'U::U()'
> /.../sketch_mar16a.ino:4:7: note: 'U::U()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
>  union U {
> ```

and

> ```
> /.../sketch_mar16a/sketch_mar16a.ino:4:7: note: 'U::~U()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
>  union U {
> ```

The presence of `String s;` in `U` is the source of the problem. You'll need to define the default constructor and the destructor in `U` and make sure you do the right thing in those functions.

The following simplified program builds on my machine.

```
struct String
{
   String(char const*) {}
   ~String() {}
};

enum E {ENUM_A,ENUM_B};
union U {
   U() : s(nullptr) {}
   ~U() {}
  String s;
  char c[4];
};
struct S {
  E e;
  U u;
};

int main()
{
   S s_arr[10];
}
```

You'll need proper implementations of `U::U()` and `U::~U()` so that your program is well behaved.